# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'img' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users`

Tags: laravel

What is the reason for the error? This has happened after changing the code of the default when registering. Please take me

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'img' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `password`, `role`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (aaaaaaa, .....G, user, 2019-01-14 16:40:05, 2019-01-14 16:40:05))
```

---

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => 'required|string|check_username|max:255|unique_username',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'captcha'=>'required|captcha'
        ],[],[
            'username'=>'user',
            'password'=>'pass',
            'captcha'=>'cap',
            'img'=>'profile',
            'fnamelname'=>'fnamelname',



        ]);
    }


protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'role'=>'user'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: There is no default value to the img column, and when you don't pass any value it fails to create a record.
Please share your user creation code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('img')->default(1);
        $table->string('fnamelname');
        $table->string('role');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

EDIT:

This is a better version

```
$table->string('img')->nullable();
```

Comment: This sets the img field to 1 by default, which introduces a weird value that you will be forced to manage afterwards. You would be better setting the field as nullable.

Comment: `$table->string('img')->nullable();` UPDATED

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('img');
        $table->string('fnamelname');
        $table->string('role');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
```

Comment: Is this your original migration? If so, please edit your question and insert it there clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If the `img` field is optional, your data model should reflect that intent clearly.

In your migration:

```
 $table->string('img')->nullable();
```

will set this column as nullable, thus you can create a record without setting a value explicitly.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns

Also, you'd better use a BLOB type instead of a string to store binary content like images. But that's another topic.